# Is It Possible to Reserve Space on a Disk in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, storage

I have a 500GB drive in my laptop with around 350GB of data. One folder on the drive is a folder that syncs with the cloud, and can have up to 100GB in it at any time.

Is there any way to limit the drive to 400GB capacity not including this folder, so an error would be produced were I to try to use more than that? Essentially I want to reserve 100GB in that one folder in case it is needed.

Third party programs are acceptable, however native solutions would be preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the purposes for partitions on disks.  Ideally you would set up a 100GB partition dedicated to this app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be considered a very broad question so I will try to cover some basics of what you are asking in a few points.

1. In a server environment you could use [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754810%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) but that does not work on a client OS and does not appear you can cheat that fact. Even so, If you were able to install it it for folder quotas not everything but a folder quota.
2. This sounds like it would be alot easier to partition your drive into a 400GB and 100GB pieces as then no monitoring would be required. You could do this with [GParted](http://gparted.org/). **Note** you would need to free 100GB of space so that you could partition it. On top of that there is always the risk that you would damage the file system so you need good back ups of your computer.
3. You could just run a script on a schedule that checks your drive / folder size and send an alert while you are logged in.
4. Didnt have much luck in the 3rd Party tools where *free* was probably a criteria of a good candidate.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't consider partitioning. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can mount thaty 100GB partition in a folder on the other drive. That make this more seamless.

Answer (score 3):

Create a virtual hard disk using disk management and mount it as a drive or a folder. You can specify the size for the drive. So windows will create a vhd file with specified size. You can either mount it as a drive or mount it as a folder.

See detailed steps here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5291/how-to-create-a-virtual-hard-drive-in-windows-7/

Comment: This also might work for me. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also mount the partition as a particular directory so it has it's own capacity but looks like it is actually a folder.

[Mount partition as folder](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/280297?wa=wsignin1.0)